# SpringBoot + RabbitMQ throwing error : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, yaml

I have hosted a multimodule project on heroku and receiving the following error when trying to run my Spring Boot Application.

```
2018-06-13T05:34:47.611296+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:34:47.611  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-06-13T05:34:47.617422+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:34:47.617  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.646470+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:34:47.646  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-06-13T05:34:47.660578+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:34:47.660  INFO 4 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680639+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:34:47.679 ERROR 4 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680646+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680648+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680650+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680656+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680658+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:34:47.680659+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1797) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
```

The issue I see is, it is trying to connect some localhost whereas I have my addon `CloudAMQP
Little Lemur` added in heroku and I have added these to my both Application.yml file:

```
spring:
    profiles: heroku
    mvc:
      async:
        request-timeout: 3600000
    rabbitmq:
      addresses: amqp://****:*****@puma.rmq.cloudamqp.com/uyjgxslh
      host: puma.rmq.cloudamqp.com
      port: 1883
      username: ****:****
      password: *****
```

In my webModule I have this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication {

    public final static String PDF_MERGE_QUEUE= "pdf-merge-queue";

    @Bean
    Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(PDF_MERGE_QUEUE, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange("pdf-nerge-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange topicExchange){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(topicExchange).with(PDF_MERGE_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(PDF_MERGE_QUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RabbitMQListener rabbitMQListener){
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(rabbitMQListener, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and in my worker module main method:

```
public class SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication {
    public final static String PDF_MERGE_QUEUE= "pdf-merge-queue";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please find below some more stack trace from Heroku logs :

```
handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-06-13T05:54:13.871350+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:13.870  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-06-13T05:54:13.897860+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:13.897  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-06-13T05:54:13.899632+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:13.899  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-06-13T05:54:13.901591+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:13.901  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-06-13T05:54:14.128560+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.128  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-13T05:54:14.145677+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.145  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-06-13T05:54:14.154055+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.153  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.199050+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.197  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-06-13T05:54:14.230846+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.230  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.425996+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.425  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-06-13T05:54:14.437981+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.435  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.e.SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication   : Started SpringBootHerokuExampleApplication in 13.198 seconds (JVM running for 14.523)
2018-06-13T05:54:14.969935+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.969  WARN 4 --- [    container-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:14.970343+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.970  INFO 4 --- [    container-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@362d89d0: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971125+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.971  INFO 4 --- [    container-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971946+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.971 ERROR 4 --- [    container-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971948+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971951+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971952+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971956+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971958+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1797) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971960+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971961+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:338) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971962+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971964+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971965+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971967+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971969+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971971+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971972+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971973+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971974+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971975+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971977+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971978+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971979+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971980+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971981+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 9 common frames omitted
2018-06-13T05:54:14.971982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T05:54:14.972042+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:14.971  INFO 4 --- [    container-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.262272+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.261  WARN 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:19.264406+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.264  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@793be5ca: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-06-13T05:54:19.272605+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.272  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.976366+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.976  WARN 4 --- [    container-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:19.976491+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.976  INFO 4 --- [    container-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@42d37ed7: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-06-13T05:54:19.977274+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.977  INFO 4 --- [    container-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978248+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.978 ERROR 4 --- [    container-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978252+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978253+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978255+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978256+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978257+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978258+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1797) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978259+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978260+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978261+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:338) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978263+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978264+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978265+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978267+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978268+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978269+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978270+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978271+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978272+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978273+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978274+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978275+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978276+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978277+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978278+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978279+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 9 common frames omitted
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T05:54:19.978370+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:19.978  INFO 4 --- [    container-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-06-13T05:54:24.281046+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:24.280  WARN 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-06-13T05:54:24.281735+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:24.281  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7170b3b5: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-06-13T05:54:24.291703+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2018-06-13 05:54:24.291  INFO 4 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
```

Why is it trying to connect to localhost when I have specified host name explicitly in yml file? Any Idea?

Comment: Clearly whatever you are trying to connect to is not listening where you are sending the connect requests.  Have you independently verified that the server is running where you expect it to be?

Comment: The server is up and running as its a heroku addon. When we click on the heroku addon then it redirects us to the page where I can see the Rabbit MQ details screen.

Comment: I can see in logs `o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]` this line, why is it trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: Just found out that in yml file I have a profile named as heroku, when I removed it , it connected to the RabbitMQ in the given host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that in yml file I have a profile named as heroku, when I removed it , it connected to the RabbitMQ in the given host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot you can configure Rabbit by spring cloud stream.
In this case you dont have to configure the beans and the configuration is much easier:

```
spring:
#---------------- RabbitMQ -----------------#
  rabbitmq:
    #Default username ans pass
    dynamic: true
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

#---------------------------- RabbitMQ properties Commons ------------------------------#
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        springCloudBusInput:
          destination: InputExchange
          group: Queue
          producer:
            exchangeAutoDelete: false
        springCloudBusOutput:
          destination: InputExchange
          group: Queue
          consumer:
            exchangeAutoDelete: false
```

Then you have to create the listener:

```
@Component
public class RemoteEventListener implements ApplicationListener<InputEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InputEvent inputEvent) {

        //whatever you want to do when a InputEvent Type is received in the queue

    }
}
```

> In this case My app is writing and receiving from the same exchange
>   and queue (Because of testing so stuff)

If you want to configure rabbit the way you shown, try to create a configuration class with the beans of the queue, exchange and biding with @Configuration. Dont declare the beans in your app class.

It seems it can not read the autodelete property of the queue, but if I'm not wrong I should take the default.
**Maybe You have network issues**
**Check the rabbitmq and restart it**

Can you acces to rabbitMq administrator interface?

About the comment about whi is trying to connect with localhost add this to your bean definition:

```
@Autowired
 private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory

@Bean
 public RabbitTemplate rubeExchangeTemplate() {
  RabbitTemplate r = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
  r.setExchange("rmq.rube.exchange");
  r.setRoutingKey("rube.key");
  r.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
  return r;
 }
```

also remove addresses of your application.yml

Comment: Rabbit MQ is installed on Heroku as addon.

Comment: I have eddited the post. I think it should be network issues because it seems everything is fine. try to restart rabbit

Comment: I reinstalled the addon, deleted the old rabbitMQ instance, still does not work. The Spring boot app which I am running has multiple applications in it. One web application and one worker application.

Comment: Why is it trying to connect to localhost when I have specified host name explicitly in yml file? Any Idea?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-rabbitmq, try to add the Connection Factory and RabbitTemplate, I have edited the post again with more info

Comment: I found out that in yml file I have a profile named as heroku, when I removed it , it connected to the RabbitMQ in the given host.